# ElasticSearch Has_Child doesn't return the results

Tags: search, full-text-search, parent-child, elasticsearch

I'm very new to ElasticSearch and trying out the parent-child relationship.

My mappings look like this

```
mappings: {

parent: {
    properties: {
        sts: {
            type: long
        }
        md: {
            type: string
        }
        dty: {
            type: string
        }
        cid: {
            type: string
        }
    }
}
child: {
    _routing: {
        required: true
    }
    _parent: {
        type: parent
    }
    properties: {
        cons: {
            type: string
        }
        ccnid: {
            type: string
        }
        nid: {
            type: string
        }
    }
}
```

}

I created the parents using the bulk API

```
{"index":{"_id":"cusId:NodeId1"," _routing":"cusId"}}
{"cid":"cusId","sts":0,"nm":"NodeId1_t"}

{"index":{"_id":"cusId:NodeId2"," _routing":"cusId"}}
{"cid":"cusId","sts":0,"nm":"NodeId2_t"}
```

I created these children

```
{"index":{"_id":"c4","_routing":"cusId","parent":"cusId:NodeId1"}}
{"cons":["animals","treat","cat","feet"],"ccnid":"cusId","nid":"NodeId1"}

{"index":{"_id":"c5","_routing":"cusId","parent":"cusId:NodeId2"}}
{"cons":["cats","animals","something"],"ccnid":"cusId","nid":"NodeId2"}
```

Now when I search for `has_child` in parent; I get nothing. 
However, if I change cons to be not an array and just a plain string with the value "animals" in it, the query returns the correct results.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "child",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "cons": "animals"
              }
            }
         ]
       }
      }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are new to elasticsearch, you need to know how ES [analyzes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html) the text you provide.

Since you are using the `term` query, ES is not going to analyze the text and is going to look for an **exact** match.

You need to change your `child` `mapping` if you want to use `term` query
like this

```
"properties": {
        "cons": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "ccnid": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "nid": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
```

If I am not wrong, You were using default [`standard analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) as you did not specify any analyzers. `index : not_analyzed` will index the term as it is.

After that below query will give you the expected results. You need to use [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query for multiple match. The query will give you parents which has either "animals" or "treat" inside the array.

```
GET parent_index/parent/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "child",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "cons": [
                  "animals",
                  "treat"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ES gives lot of ways to [query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl.html) your data, based on what you want